# Error with -mno-sse flag and gettimeofday() in C

Tags: c, gcc, gettimeofday

A simple C program which uses gettimeofday() works fine when compiled without any flags ( gcc-4.5.1) but doesn't give output when compiled with the flag -mno-sse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval s,e;
    float time;
    int i;
    gettimeofday(&s, NULL);
    for( i=0; i< 10000; i++);
    gettimeofday(&e, NULL);
    time = e.tv_sec - s.tv_sec + e.tv_usec - s.tv_usec;
    printf("%f\n", time);
    return 0;
}
```

I have CFLAGS=-march=native -mtune=native
Could someone explain why this happens?
The program returns a correct value normally, but prints "0" when compiled with -mno-sse enabled.

Comment: By the way, your calculation seems wrong - it would give the same result for a time difference of 1.000001 seconds as it would for 0.000002 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag `-mno-sse` causes floating point arguments to be passed on the stack, whereas the usual x86_64 ABI specifies that they should be passed via SSE registers.

Since `printf()` in your C library was compiled *without* `-mno-sse`, it is expecting floating point arguments to be passed in accordance with the ABI.  This is why your code fails.  It has nothing to do with `gettimeofday()`.

If you wish to use `printf()` from your code compiled with `-mno-sse` and pass it floating point arguments, you will need to recompile your C library with that option and link against that version.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using a loop which does nothing in order to observe a time difference. The problem is, the compiler may optimize this loop away entirely. The issue may not be with the `-mno-sse` itself, but may be that that allows an optimization that removes the loop, thus giving you the same time each time you run it.

I would recommend trying to put something in that loop which can't be optimized out (such as incrementing a number which you print out at the end). See if you still get the same behavior. If not, I'd recommend looking at the generated assembler `gcc -S` and see what the code difference is.

Comment: I have just used this as an example. The issue is still present irrespective of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The datastructures tv_usec and tv_sec are usually longs.
Redeclaration of the variable "time" as a long integer solved the issue.

The following link addresses the issue.
http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2006-10/msg00525.html
Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval s,e;
    long time;
    int i;
    gettimeofday(&s, NULL);
    for( i=0; i< 10000; i++);
    gettimeofday(&e, NULL);
    time = e.tv_sec - s.tv_sec + e.tv_usec - s.tv_usec;
    printf("%ld\n", time);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the prompt replies. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `doesn't give output`?

0 (zero) is a perfectly reasonable output to expect.

---

Edit: Try compiling to assembler (`gcc -S ...`) and see the differences between the normal and the no-sse version.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant that it gives no meaningful output. It is not supposed to give a Zero.